# Creating a Poker Hand Analyzer in python

Tags: python, dictionary, poker

so, i'm trying to pull a C out of my python class and my final project is killing me.  first we had to create the deck of cards using a dictionary and a list.  i got that to work.

```
suits = {0: "Hearts", 1: "Diamonds", 2: "Clubs", 3: "Spades"}
ranks = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13)
card_deck = []

def create_deck():
    for suit in suits:
        for rank in ranks:
            card_deck.append([rank, suit])

create_deck()
```

now i have to create a function to associate the list entries with the actual card.  so, 1, 0 will read Ace of Hearts and so on.  i have no clue clue how to do this.  anybody have any suggestions or possibly links?  we got hints of:

card = (1,0) index the tuple to get the suit
suit=card[1] now take the suit and plug it into the dictionary to get the appropriate text
suit_text=suits[suit]

it looks like i need to create a new dictionary with the face cards in it

```
cards = {1: "Ace", 11: "Jack", 12: "Queen", 13: "King"}
```

but how do i get them to associate to the list entries??

Comment: can you explain by `associate the list entries with the actual card...`

Comment: do you wish to have a new dictionary whereby the keys are unique and are related to the number and suit of a card?... e.g. `{ "1H": "Ace of hearts", "2C": "2 of Clubs", "13S": "King of Spades"... }`

Comment: currently i have the cards in a list stored as (rank , suit), now i need to end up with a list that has 1, 0: Ace of Hearts, 2, 0: 2 of Hearts and so on

Comment: i still dont get it - please elaborate

Comment: sorry, got wrapped up in other issues.  i ended up figuring it out.  answer posted below.  this project has me all screwed up.  can't even describe the thing properly.

Comment: As an aside, you can create the deck in a single line with list comprehension: `card_deck=[[rank,suit] for rank in ranks for suit in suits]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after some work, i figured it out.

```
def print_card():
    for card in card_deck:
        suit = card[1]
        suit_text = suits[suit]
        if card[0] == 1 or card[0] == 11 or card[0] == 12 or card[0] == 13:
            rank = card[0]
            rank_text = face_cards[rank]
        else:
            rank = card[0]
            rank_text = ranks[rank] - 1

        print (str(rank_text) + " of " + suit_text)

print_card()
```